# "NSMutableData data retain" on NSURLConnection - how calm this works?

Tags: loops, nsurlconnection, retain

On a lot of `NSURLConnection` examples I see the following lines:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(theConnection)
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
}
else
    ...
```

I wonder - what is this supposed to do? and why does it work? I thought that `data` is an accessor method, and since your not calling it on an instanciated object, it will return `nil`, and by retaining it you actually do nothing.

This is the way I have seen to get data on connections like this:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
if( connection )
{
    while (!finished) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
}
```

`finished` is an ivar that gets set to `YES` on `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

Can anyone clear this up for me? Which should be used and what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSMutableData data]` is not an accessor but a so-called *class method*. You probably know `[NSMutableData alloc]`, that too is a class method and means it is tied to the class but not an instance. The typical way to denote that a method is a class method is by prefixing it with a plus: `+[NSMutableData data]`.

In this case, the method is inherited from the `NSData` class (but does return an `NSMutableData` instance, since you're calling it on that class).

An implementation might look like this:

```
@interface NSMutableData
+ (id)data
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
@end
```

Note that `self` in this case is the `NSMutableData` class.

In other languages like C++, C# and Java (AFAIK) these would be methods that you specify with the `static` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) and how about the while( !finished ) loop? because I've never seen it on an example but that's the only way I can get the data fetched, otherwise its empty, since I use a custom class just for the fetching, there for I need to return it in the very same message the connection is created, and If I just do if( !connection) { ... } return self.recievedData the data is returned before the connection got back, but I cant return it from the didRecieveData since its a void message.

Comment: The `while` loop is a something you shouldn't do as it's bad design. It seems that the method in questions wants to block until it has all the data. Use asynchronuous design instead and spare yourself the trouble and bugs that result from messing with the run loop.

Comment: you mean, instead of checking that way if the fetching is done and return the data to the sender, just combine the data fetching & processing classes and call to the processing method from DidFinishLoading?